# Python - Keeping a user input box above continually printing text in a while loop

Tags: python, multithreading, user-input, python-multithreading

I am trying to write a Python program that loops a program in the background and waits for user input do either perform an action in the loop or exit the loop. There are three main parts to the code:

- Program continually running and plotting out temperature and pH values (this runs in a thread)
- Program to perform a frequency reading (activated by user entering 'FREQ' into input)
- Exiting the loop and closing the thread (activated by user entering 'EXIT' into input)

The issue I'm running into is that I want to keep the user input box above the continual prints from the loop printing out temperature and pH values.

I've tried to rearrange when the thread starts and where the user input appears but it looks like the thread needs to be above the while loop checking for user input. Because of this, if something is entered into the input box it will begin to place the input box below the most recent print statement (which is annoying to track). I've also tried using a display (from IPython.display) but am not sure if it's possible to initialize a display and place the user input box into this display to stay above the print statements.

The code below is what I have so far but the user input eventually ends up printing below the mos recent temperature and pH text printouts.

```
import threading
import time
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

# FUNCTIONS

def freq_sweep():
    print('-------freq sweep STARTED')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('-------freq sweep FINISHED')

def temp_pH_reading_plotting():
    print(f"Temp: 100, pH: 10")
    time.sleep(1)

def run_loop():
    global stop_loop
    while not stop_loop:
        
        temp_pH_reading_plotting()
        
        if stop_loop:
            break

# MAIN CODE

# Define a global variable to control the loop
stop_loop = False

# Create a thread for the loop
loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop)
loop_thread.start()

# Listen for user input
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter 'EXIT' to stop the loop or 'FREQ' to do a frequency sweep: ")

    if user_input == 'EXIT':
        stop_loop = True
        print("Exiting program...")
        break
    elif user_input == 'FREQ':
        freq_sweep()


# Wait for the loop thread to finish
loop_thread.join()
print("Program has ended.")
```

The picture below is how the code starts when nothing is entered into the text box and I'd like to keep it this way.

[image: Ideal placement of input box (and starting position at code initiation)]

But whenever text is entered, the user input starts to print below the recent print statement as shown below:

[image: User input box appears below recent print statements]

Note, the code does work to activate the frequency sweep (as seen in image 2) and is able to exit the code when 'EXIT' is input into the user input box, but the input box does not stay in one place.

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem or suggestions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a library like [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm).
There is an example of how you can write to many lines in parallel here: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/examples/parallel_bars.py

A simple example of lines updating in parallel would be:

```
import time
import random
import string
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
from tqdm import tqdm


sensor_data = deque()

def fetch_sensor_data(sensor_data):
    while True:
        # simulate fetching some data
        time.sleep(1)
        random_string = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=8))
        sensor_data.append(random_string)

sensor_thread = Thread(target=fetch_sensor_data, args=(sensor_data,))
sensor_thread.start()

first_bar = tqdm(None, bar_format='{desc}')
second_bar = tqdm(None, bar_format='{desc}')

def display_lines(sensor_data, first_bar, second_bar):
    while True:
        if len(sensor_data):
            first_bar.set_description_str(f'Top line: {sensor_data.popleft()}')
        random_value = random.randint(1,1000)
        if random_value % 10 == 0:
            second_bar.set_description_str(f"Static text before -- {random_value} -- Static text after")
        time.sleep(0.1)


display_thread = Thread(target=display_lines, args=(sensor_data, first_bar, second_bar))
display_thread.start()
```

You could also play around with `'\033[A'` as this will tell the terminal to go up one line. You can find some useful information here: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

```
- Position the Cursor:
  \033[<L>;<C>H
     Or
  \033[<L>;<C>f
  puts the cursor at line L and column C.
- Move the cursor up N lines:
  \033[<N>A
- Move the cursor down N lines:
  \033[<N>B
- Move the cursor forward N columns:
  \033[<N>C
- Move the cursor backward N columns:
  \033[<N>D
- Clear the screen, move to (0,0):
  \033[2J
- Erase to end of line:
  \033[K
- Save cursor position:
  \033[s
- Restore cursor position:
  \033[u
```